# Flutter Syncfusion PDF and Images failing

Tags: flutter, image, pdf, syncfusion

I cannot get a document that is created to work at all when I incorporate and image anywhere on the page.  It will work when running through the IDE but not once I build the package.  I'm running it as a Windows Program (doesn't work on iOS or Android either, only when emulated).

I used their direct code sample from from the Syncfusion Documentation as such and just updating the image location and LTWH:

```
final Uint8List imageData = File('assets/images/seallogol.png').readAsBytesSync();
//Load the image using PdfBitmap.
final PdfBitmap image = PdfBitmap(imageData);
//Draw the image to the PDF page.
document.pages
    .add()
    .graphics
    .drawImage(image, const Rect.fromLTWH(225, 0, 60, 60));
```

This above code did not work once you clicked to create the PDF file.  It just did nothing.
while running in the emulator, it did run without any issues at all.  This was not idea because it creates a brand new page and just sticks the logo on that new page.  This did not seem to be an issue so I used the following code instead:

```
    final Uint8List imageData = File('assets/images/seallogo.png').readAsBytesSync();
    final PdfBitmap image = PdfBitmap(imageData);
    page.graphics.drawImage(image, const Rect.fromLTWH(225, 0, 60, 60));
```

In the emulator, it did exactly what I wanted it to do.  Still, wouldn't do anything after it was built and ran.  Nothing at all.  I know my other code is good.  All I do is remove the 3 lines of code, build it, and it runs flawlessly so I know that something with writing the image is where it breaks down.
I am using the current version: syncfusion_flutter_pdf 24.1.43

I just cant seem to figure this out as to why.  And why it will run for testing in the IDE without any issues at all.  Once its built, it will not run on the same PC or any other.  Windows 10 or 11.

I have tried re-writing the image code, tried different image types and still have the same result.  I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1):

We suspect that the issue in release builds may be due to loading the image data from assets using "**File**", since certain features of "**dart:io**" may be restricted in release builds for desktop and mobile platforms (Android and iOS).

Use the following alternative way to retrieve the image data from assets,

- Add the package “**import 'package:flutter/services.dart';**” in your dart file.
- Use the following code to retrieve image data,

  ```
   //Load the image using PdfBitmap.
   final PdfBitmap image = PdfBitmap(await _readImageData(seallogol.png));
   //Draw the image to the PDF page.
   page.graphics.drawImage(image, const Rect.fromLTWH(225, 0, 60, 60));
  ```

Write the following code on the **_readImageData**.

```
Future<List<int>> _readImageData(String name) async {
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/ $name');
return data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
}
```

To know more about adding images to PDF documents using our Syncfusion Flutter PDF, refer to the following UG links,

[How to convert images to PDF in Syncfusion Flutter PDF Library? | Syncfusion](https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10453/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf-in-syncfusion-flutter-pdf-library)

[Images in Flutter PDF library | Syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-images#inserting-an-image-in-pdf-document)